# Oracle regex expression evaluates to false

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a regular expression which in my java application is used to evaluate a username `^[-\w.+_@]{1,120}$`

https://regexr.com/6vhsf
In Regexr, test 1,2,3 passes as expected.

I want to apply the same username check in a piece of PL/SQL code, however in Oracle the same expression always evaluates to false
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c33a/156

Why does Oracle evaluate the expression differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does Oracle evaluate the expression differently?

Oracle does not match `\w` as a word-character within a character group it matches it as the individual characters `\` and `w`.

*Note: do not use `regexr.com` to test Oracle regular expressions as Oracle does not support the same regular expression syntax as is tested on that website.*

If you want to match the equivalent of `\w` within a bracket expression then you can match the underscore `_` and either `0-9a-zA-Z` or the POSIX character class `[:alnum:]`.

So either:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   device
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(x, '^[0-9a-zA-Z.+_@-]{1,120}$')
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   device
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(x, '^[[:alnum:].+_@-]{1,120}$')
```

*Note 2: When matching `-` then it either needs to be first or last in the bracket expression. However, if you need to match both `]` and `-` in a bracket expression then `]` must be the first character and `-` the last character so it is a good habit to always put the `-` as the last character in the bracket.*