How to tell oracle SQL the backslash in regex is no escape symbol
The query select regexp_replace('Wd+Wd4Wd', '[\W\d]+', '_') from dual outputs _+_4_, meaning it treats the backslash as escape character and replaces W and d instead of + and 4. It works if \W and \d are not used in brackets: select regexp_replace('Wd+Wd4Wd', '(\W|\d)+', '_') from dual outputs Wd_Wd_Wd as expected.
How can I match non-word characters and digits within brackets?

This is a known issue that Oracle regex does not allow Perl-like shorthand character classes inside bracket expressions, see Oracle regex expression evaluates to false, for example.
You can use POSIX character classes inside bracket expressions. For this concrete scenario, you can use
select regexp_replace('Wd+Wd4Wd', '[[:digit:][:punct:][:space:]]+', '_') from dual

To match digits, [:digit:] or 0-9 can work.
As for non-word characters, I think you just want to match punctuation and whitespace, so [:punct:] and [:space:] POSIX character classes should be enough.

Thank you, this works! Do you have an explanation why the regexp behaves like that? Why is it escaping within brackets but not escaping without brackets?

@NablaDelta See my answer for the explanation.

@NablaDelta The explanation has already been given: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73973150/3832970 for example.

This answer is subtly wrong for the underscore character. (\W|\d)+ will not match an underscore but [[:digit:][:punct:][:space:]]+ will.

@MT0 While it is true that [:punct:] matches an underscore, the solution is anyway correct for the given scenario (as OP replaces with an underscore) and for a lot of those cases where people actually think of an underscore as punctuation and not a word char.

This is only an explanation what happens but not why Oracle decided to implement it like that :) weird behavior!

@NablaDelta Why Oracle developers decided to use their own implementation of POSIX ERE  regex standard is a question that I think only they can answer.

@NablaDelta Also, just for you to avoid more confusions: [a-z] is a character class in the NFA regex "world", \w etc. are shorthand character classes. In a POSIX regex "world", [a-z] is a bracket expression and [:digit:] is a (POSIX) character class. Since Oracle uses a POSIX compliant regex (with some twists) you should stick to the POSIX regex terminology.


The query select regexp_replace('Wd+Wd4Wd', '[\W\d]+', '_') from dual outputs _+_4_, meaning it treats the backslash as escape character and replaces W and d instead of + and 4.

Not quite, Oracle does not treat the backslash as an escape character in a character class (and does not support PERL-like expressions in character classes).
In Oracle, [\W\d] means either the character \ or W or \ or d.
If you were to use:
SELECT regexp_replace('\Wd\\+W\\d4\W\d\', '[\W\d]+', '_') AS replacement
FROM   DUAL;

Then the output is:



REPLACEMENT




_+_4_



You can see it has matched sequence of either \ or W or d and replaced them all with _.

To get your output your desired output, you can use:
SELECT regexp_replace('Wd+Wd4Wd', '(\W|\d)+', '_') AS replacement
FROM   DUAL;

or:
SELECT regexp_replace('Wd+Wd4Wd', '[^[:alpha:]_]+', '_') AS replacement
FROM   DUAL;

or:
SELECT regexp_replace('Wd+Wd4Wd', '[^A-Za-z_]+', '_') AS replacement
FROM   DUAL;

Which all output:



REPLACEMENT




Wd_Wd_Wd



fiddle

"Oracle does not treat the backslash as an escape character in a character class (and does not support PERL-like expressions in character classes)" This can't be true since the character classes ARE working if they are not within brackets? Why is \W treated differently whether it's surrounded by brackets or not? Why is \W different from [\W]?

@NablaDelta It is true. PERL-like regular expressions are supported outside of character classes (so you can use \W for non-word characters) but they are not supported inside character classes (so [\W] is the same as (\\|W) and is not the same as [^[:word:]]).

Sorry you're right, I misunderstood "character classes". Still a very strange behavior for me...
